# Api call in php with credentials

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, get, php-curl

I'm using the cURL setup on [this page](https://weichie.com/blog/curl-api-calls-with-php/) to make my API calls in php.

The function call goes as follows: `callAPI($method, $url, $data)`. I've made it work with a `('GET', 'URL', false)` API call so the code does work.

Now I want to make a call to a different api. The data inputs I need to give are these:

```
Array
(
    [Credentials] => Credentials Object
        (
            [Account] => my_account_name
            [Password] => my_password
        )

)
```

So this will need to be my `$data` object I believe?

I'm new to php so I don't know how I should setup my code to make this work with these data inputs.

Can somebody please help me how I should make these inputs in my API call?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a $data= json_encode($your_array); on that array before passing it to your function

Comment: `Now I want to make a call to a different api.` Whats the dest api?

Comment: It's called TabT api, documentation can be found here: 'http://api.frenoy.net/' & http://ttc-erembodegem.be/tabtapi-test/. It should be connecting to the vttl database so as seen on the second link I think I should connect to 'VTTL WSDL: https://api.vttl.be/?wsdl'.